# ggtern custom function object x not found error

Tags: r, function, ggtern

I'm trying to create a custom function that draws a ternary plot using the package `ggtern`

Here is an example of the data and the function

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtern)

myData <- tibble(T_x = c(0.461, 0.778, 0.429),
             T_y = c(0.126, 0.108, 0.404),
             T_z = c(0.413, 0.114, 0.167))

drawTriad <- function(df, x, y, z) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  z <- enquo(z)
  df %>% 
    ggtern::ggtern(aes(!!x,
                       !!y,
                       !!z)) +
    geom_point(size = 2, color = "blue") +
    theme_void() + 
    theme_hidelabels() +
    theme(tern.axis.line = element_line(color='darkgray',size=1.5))
}
```

When I run the function on myData like this:

`drawTriad(myData, T_x, T_y, T_z)`

I'm getting the following error: **Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found**

How can I get this simple function to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options...

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(tibble)
library(ggtern)
```

**Option 1**

This is simpler: just rename the variables in the source data frame or tibble to suit ggtern, this avoids the issue of programmatic variables for the point coordinates.

```
drawTriad <- function(df) {
  df %>% 
    ggtern::ggtern(aes(x, y, z)) +
    geom_point(size = 2, color = "blue") +
    theme_void() + 
    theme_hidelabels() +
    theme(tern.axis.line = element_line(color='darkgray',size=1.5))
}

drawTriad(myData)
```

[image]

**Option 2**

This is based on the explanation given in ggplot2: elegant graphics for data analysis https://ggplot2-book.org/programming.html. And matches the problem set out in the question.

```r
drawTriad <- function(df, x, y, z) {

  df %>% 
    ggtern::ggtern(aes_(x = as.name(x), y = as.name(y), z = as.name(z))) +
    geom_point(size = 2, color = "blue") +
    theme_void() + 
    theme_hidelabels() +
    theme(tern.axis.line = element_line(color='darkgray',size=1.5))
}

drawTriad(df = myData,
          x = "T_x",
          y = "T_y",
          z = "T_z")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Peter! This worked! Why would the enquo() and !! not work in this case though?

Comment: From ggplot book: "aes() uses non-standard evaluation: rather than looking at the values of its arguments, it looks at their expressions. This makes it difficult to work with programmatically as there’s no way to store the name of a variable in an object and then refer to it later:" Hence  use aes_(), which uses regular evaluation. In short it is different from programmatic use of , say, `dplyr `.